# the path specified is not a directory or doesn't contain a package.xml

Tags: trailhead, salesforcedx-cli, force-cli

I don't understand what is wrong in "Convert the Source and Push It to a New Scratch Org" from trail "Convert and Deploy an Existing App". I get this error:

```
the path specified is not a directory or doesn't contain a package.xml.
```

Here is what I have in PowerShell:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that either the `mdapipackage` folder you're referencing in your command does not exist or that it does exist and it does not include a package.xml file.

From your command history it appears that you are running the command from inside of the `mdapipackage` folder. The command looks for the `mdapipackage` folder inside of your current working directory. Since you're inside of the folder you're trying to convert, the command is failing.

To fix the error you can navigate one level up and run the command from the `MutualFundExplorer` folder instead.